# VirtualBox clone & resize data loss

Tags: virtualbox, recovery

One of my Virtualbox VMs was running low on space so I decided to go and resize its hard drive.
The VM used a VMDK file, which I couldn't resize through VBox so I had to clone it first.

So I cloned the file to a VDI one, resized that one, booted on a gParted iso to resize the partition and booted the OS fine. That given I deleted the original VMDK (*facepalm*).
Now I started using my VM a bit more and noticed files and folders are not in the state I left them when I shut down the machine, but in a state they were several weeks ago.

I suppose something went wront because I had made a snapshot of that VM and was working on that snapshot, which didn't write to the HDD VMDK. I have one snapshot's file, a VMDK in my Snapshot folder.

So here are my questions :
 - What happened exactly ?
 - Does that snapshot VMDK still contain my up to date file or did I lose my work ?
 - If the data is still there, how can I recover it ?

(Btw I'm runnning on a SSD drive so I don't think it's worth talking about recovering the deleted VMDK file.)

Comment: Hi, regarding that this is a programmer-site and not a software-question-site, I voted to move this to superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it seems I was able to recover a file I wanted by using The Sleuth Kit on the snapshot VMDK.

So if anyone wonders, TSK tools can load a VMDK image using the *-i afflib* switch.